# Google IAM api to add GSuite domain wide delegation

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-api-java-client, google-authentication

I am working on a application that is using google service account with domain wide delegation.

I don't want client to do setting of domain wide delegation and download private key. I could create private key using IAM api.

is there a way to achieve domain wide delegation also via API ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Google's IAM API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/) is part of their Google Cloud API's. As far as I'm aware, there is no equivalent API for standard Google developer project IAM, which is where you would do anything around projects targeting G Suite API's (and the only place where there is a Domain Wide Delegation setting for a service account, AFAIK).

Comment: Thanks for answer. The place where we do domain wide deligation, its the same place where we create privatekey. But Using API call I am able to create/delete private key, Also update service account. I suspect there should be some way to enable domain wide delegation also.

Comment: Not seeing anything about setting domain wide delegation on the API documentation, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You can grant a service account permission at the Organization level in Google Cloud, but I'm not sure whether that has any effect on the GSuite access controls, as nferrell mentions.